# Draw a Simple circle using percentage like chart?

Tags: php, css

Without any **external link** I want to draw a circle using "%" like chart.

Like **this** barchart in the code below:

```
$val="46%"; echo "
<table width=100% border=0.1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table height=1 3 width=$val% border=0 bgcolor=red>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right><font size=1><b>$val</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";

$val="73%"; echo "
<table width=100% border=0.1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table height = 13 width=$val% border=0 bgcolor=red>
                <tr>
                    <td align=right>
                        <font size=1><b>$val</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: You can have a look at this js library http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="chart1" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="chart2" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var chart1 = document.getElementById('chart1');
      var context = chart1.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = chart1.width / 2;
      var centerY = chart1.height / 2;
      var radius = 70;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.strokeStyle = '#333333';
      context.stroke();
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, (2 * .46) * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
  
      context.font = "30px Arial";      
      context.textAlign = 'center';
      context.textBaseline = 'middle'; 
      context.fillStyle = 'black';
      context.fillText("46%",centerX, centerY);
      
      var chart2 = document.getElementById('chart2');
      context = chart2.getContext('2d');
      centerX = chart2.width / 2;
      centerY = chart2.height / 2;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.strokeStyle = '#333333';
      context.stroke();
      
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, (2 * .73) * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fill();
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Idk what's up with that script error, runs fine in a browser.

Comment: Thank You @Rob Wood  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, (2 * <?php echo $p; ?>) * Math.PI, false);

Comment: Accepting the answer would be appreciated, if it solves your problem. =}

Comment: ofcourse really hepful!!! added multiple divisions..
 Is there any option to put value(text) inside?
`code
var t=226;
var n = 23/tv;
var r = 43/tv;
var c = 20/tv;
var f = 140/tv;
var s1 = 0;
var e1 = n * 2 * Math.PI;
var s2 = e1;
var e2 = e1 + r * 2 * Math.PI;
var s3 = e2;
var e3 = e2 + c * 2 * Math.PI;
var s4 = e3;
var e4 = e3 + f * 2 * Math.PI;
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, s1, e1, false);
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, s2, e2, false);
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, s3, e3, false);
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, s4, e4, false);`

Comment: See the edited example. HTML5 Canvas is pretty easy to use.